# Not able to make a network request from FileProvider extension on iOS

Tags: ios, alamofire

I am writing a FileProvider extension (NSFileProviderExtension) for iOS. When "itemChangedAtURL" is called, I want to take the data from the NSURL and commit it back to my server.  The problem I am having is that I will use Alamofire to make a request call and the request will never fire.  I have tried setting backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier and using a sharedContainerIdentifier but none of that worked either.  The same alamofire calls worked outside of the FileProvider extension.  Does anyone know how exactly I have to setup NSURLSession or Alamofire to get this to work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this similar problem with AFNetworking. I decided to wrap my calls in a block based on what I read in http://z43studio.com/2015/04/storage-providers/

```
override func itemChangedAtURL(url: NSURL) {
    var manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()   
    var request = manager.requestSerializer.multipartFormRequestWithMethod("PUT", URLString: "http://somewhere.awesome", parameters: nil, constructingBodyWithBlock: { (data: AFMultipartFormData!) -> Void in
            var res = data.appendPartWithFileURL(fileUrl, name: "custom_name", error: nil)
    }, error: nil)

    var semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)         
    let task:NSURLSessionDataTask = manager.uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest(request, progress: nil,
        completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!, responseObject: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if ((error) != nil) {
                println("ERROR")
                // Attempt to recover - otherwise release
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
            } else {
                println("SUCCESS")
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
            }

    })

    task.resume()
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
}
```